# Free energy a continuous function of temperature but may not be differentiable everywhere?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

So according to my understanding, the free energy of the system should be a continuous function of temperature. This is because if the free energy is not continuous at temperature T, then at this temperature the free energy can have two values (i.e. two states) and the two states will mix to eliminate the difference in their free energies.

Is that a reasonable explanation for the continuity of free energy?

The free energy is a continuous function of temperature does not mean it is differentiable everywhere, because at the point where the phase coexistence start to occur the free energy is not differentiable. Is that the case?

Comment: Just commenting on the concept of "differentiable."  A function can be everywhere continuous (and single-valued) yet not differentiable. It's not necessary for there to be a double-valued point or a discontinuity.